# Angularjs w/ wufoo form won't load

Tags: javascript, angularjs, wufoo

I have a single page website with "sections" (basically pages pulled in by ng-view), in the contact section I have a wufoo form. This form only loads if I refresh the contact page, if I navigate from any other page it doesn't load.

Any suggestions?